# Is there a way to submit form data in WordPress using WPForms (Pro) from inside another function?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am looking for a way to be able to submit data in a function to my WPForm in my WordPress theme.

I'd like to be able to use the data collected from outside of the typical WPForm, but still have it submitted into the same entries area of the WPForm.

After looking at some of the developer resources on the WPForms site, it looks like they offer a few hooks you can plug into, but I was not sure if any of them were to save form data, or just alter form data.